# "Best" way to generate random floats?

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

I'm working on a program that performs a lot of calculations based on chance (crazy, huh!), and to make the calculations easier to tweak to the nth degree I've been working with floating point numbers.

The basic format I've been using is along the lines of:

```
event_chance = 47.25
randnum = random.uniform(0.01, 100.0)
if randnum <= event_chance:
    do_something
else:
    dont
```

This seems to me to work OK, but I know floats work in mysterious ways... Am I getting the results that I think I am? ie. are my events firing at the defined chance that I set?

Comment: without digging too much - resetting the seed for random generator should be sufficient? random.seed(x) is where you change your seed.

Comment: I am dubious about the choice of 0.01 rather than 0 as the low end - it seems very arbitrary. However, you should be able to unit test it. Collect a few million samples, counting how many times you hit each branch of your if-statement. Is it close enough to the target frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your probabilities are slightly off, by 0.01%.

For things like this, I would tend to use random() directly - it will return a floating point from 0 to 1 - it may be 0, it will never be 1. So `if (random.random()>=0.4725): ...` - at worst the error should be 1/(2**19937-1)

Note that, when asking for a random number in a specified range, some random number generators DO, while others DO NOT include the high number (so a random *integer* with a low of 0, and a high of 3, for some random number generators will return 0, 1, or 2, whereas others may return 0, 1, 2, or 3). Read the documentation.

In the case of random.uniform, `The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().` For floating point numbers, this is, of course, much less of an issue.

Of course, comparing two floating-point numbers with '=' is always risky.